# Calling ServiceBus from Azure Automation runnBook

Tags: c#, powershell, azure, automation

I have a dll which writes a message to Azure ServiceBus

### This dll is consumed from Azure Runbook which is an powershell script. When it try to do this i get the below error. Any idea on this??

Inner Exception Message: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.NetworkDetector' threw an exception.
Inner Exception Stacktrace:    at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.NetworkDetector.BeginCheckConnectivity(IEnumerable`1 addresses, Int32 tcpPort, TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.EnumerateSteps(CurrentThreadType state)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.Start()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Amqp.AmqpMessagingFactory.ConnectAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result, ConnectInfo& info)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Amqp.FaultTolerantObject`1.CreateAsyncResult.<>c.b__5_1(CreateAsyncResult thisPtr, IAsyncResult r)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.EnumerateSteps(CurrentThreadType state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Amqp.FaultTolerantObject`1.OnEndCreateInstance(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.SingletonManager`1.EndGetInstance(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Amqp.AmqpMessagingFactory.OpenLinkAsyncResult.<>c.<GetAsyncSteps>b__35_3(OpenLinkAsyncResult thisPtr, IAsyncResult r)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.EnumerateSteps(CurrentThreadType state)
Inner Exception Message: Unable to find an entry point named 'GetPerAdapterInfo' in DLL 'iphlpapi.dll'.
Inner Exception Stacktrace:    at System.Net.NetworkInformation.UnsafeNetInfoNativeMethods.GetPerAdapterInfo(UInt32 IfIndex, SafeLocalFree pPerAdapterInfo, UInt32& pOutBufLen)
   at System.Net.NetworkInformation.SystemIPv4InterfaceProperties.GetPerAdapterInfo(UInt32 index)
   at System.Net.NetworkInformation.SystemIPv4InterfaceProperties..ctor(FixedInfo fixedInfo, IpAdapterAddresses ipAdapterAddresses)
   at System.Net.NetworkInformation.SystemIPInterfaceProperties..ctor(FixedInfo fixedInfo, IpAdapterAddresses ipAdapterAddresses)
   at System.Net.NetworkInformation.SystemNetworkInterface..ctor(FixedInfo fixedInfo, IpAdapterAddresses ipAdapterAddresses)
   at System.Net.NetworkInformation.SystemNetworkInterface.GetNetworkInterfaces()
   at System.Net.NetworkInformation.SystemNetworkInterface.InternalGetIsNetworkAvailable()
   at System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkChange.AvailabilityChangeListener.Start(NetworkAvailabilityChangedEventHandler caller)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.NetworkDetector..cctor()

BELOW IS THE SCRIPT

$connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"

```
# Get the connection "AzureRunAsConnection "
$servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName         

"Logging in to Azure..."
Add-AzureRmAccount 
   -ServicePrincipal 
   -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId
   -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId 
   -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint 

InlineScript
{
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\Modules\User\TestAutomationServiceBus\Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll")

}
ls c:\modules\user\TestAutomationServiceBus
inlinescript {[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("C:\Modules\User\TestAutomationServiceBus\TestAutomationServiceBus.dll")}
inlinescript{ [TestAutomationServiceBus.TestAutomationServiceBus]::Main()}
```

}

Above is my script. TestAutomationServiceBus.dll contains c# code to connect to ServiceBus and add message

Below is c# script
var connectionString = "Endpoi";
            var queueName = "mustang-audit-q";

```
        var client = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, queueName);

        var message = new BrokeredMessage("This is a test message from Automation!");
        //message.TimeToLive = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
        //Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Message id: {0}", message.MessageId));

        client.Send(message);
        return message.MessageId;
```

Comment: Could you please post more details about your script?  I guess maybe something wrong with the script. Besides, we couldn't find the directly  reason just by the error message.

Comment: Zhand,  Added Powershell script and c# code

Comment: According to your description, I have created a test automation. But I couldn't add the Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll to the automation Modules by using azure portal Add Module. It always show failed. How could you add the  Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll to automation Modules? My ServiceBus library  version is 4.1.3.

Comment: I did the below InlineScript
    {
       [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\Modules\User\TestAutomationServiceBus\Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll")

    }

Comment: What I mean is how you add the dll to automation modules. Do you use the portal to install the  module? Like [this](https://imgur.com/a/zohPt).

Comment: I added the dll to the zip file along with TestAutomationServiceBus.dll adn imported to the Azutomation account. does that anwer ur question